# Adding hover tooltips to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I would like to add hover tooltips to my input and output boxes on a shiny app that is deployed in shinyapps.io.

I found the `RLumShiny` package which can add tooltips and I have modified my app to accommodate this. The app works locally but when I try to deploy it to shinyapps.io I end up with the error seen below. There are no companion files to the app - just the `ui.R` and `server.R` files.

To deploy I run

```
library(rsconnect)
deployApp('~/sandbox/overdiag/', logLevel="verbose")
```

I get an error message

> ----- Deployment error -----
>
> Error: C stack usage  7969336 is too close to the limit

(and a bunch of other information from the track). I've made a minimal example that produces the same error where the `ui.R` is

```
## ui.R ##                                                                                                                                                
library("shiny")
library("RLumShiny")      ## This package is problematic
library("shinydashboard")
library("shinyWidgets")

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)
```

and `server.R`

```
library("shiny")
library("RLumShiny")   ## Again this package
library("shinydashboard")

function(input, output, session) {

}
```

Now if I remove the `library("RLumShiny")` line then everything works fine and I can deploy it right away. I don't get information that the package is not available but maybe there is something else wrong (I have a nagging feeling that the javascript in the package might do some things that the shinyapps.io service does not like).

Now: is there an alternative approach (ie., some other package) to get hover tooltips on the shinyapps.io or can I do something else to get `RLumShiny` to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general in `shiny` you can get tooltips by using `tags$div` in your `ui.r` to wrap your controls / outputs and giving it a `title`. So for example you could do:

```
tags$div(title="My tooltip", plotOutput(outputId="MyPlot"))
```

and you will get a tool tip.  The same pattern works for controls.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that was a major case of missing the right keywords on my internet search